# How can I get the gridview index in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

This is part of my code:

```
@override
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
             child: DraggableScrollbar.semicircle(
                controller: _controller,
                child: GridView.builder(
                    controller: _controller,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    itemCount: 8,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[

                            new Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              color: Colors.grey[200],
                                child: new Image.network(
                                  globals.images[index],
                                  // size setting
                                )
                            ),
                            new Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            child: Container(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                              Flexible(
                              fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: new Down(),
                                     ),
                                    Expanded(
                                         child: new comment(),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: new star()
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                      ]
                            )
                      )
                            )
                      ]
                      );
                 }
                      ),
                      ),
    )
                )
                );
  }
}

class _StarC extends State<star> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new LikeButton(
         // color setting
    ),
    likeBuilder: (bool isLiked) {
    return Icon(
    isLiked? Icons.star_rounded : Icons.star_border_rounded,
    color: isLiked ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.grey,
    size: 34,
    );
    },
      onTap: onLikeButtonTapped,
    );
  }
}

Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool isLiked) async{
  isLiked ? globals.Falist.removeAt(0) : globals.Falist.insert(0, globals.images[1]) ;
  return !isLiked;
}
```

I'm making the gallery app and know
I tried to use `globals.Falist.insert(0, globals.images[index]) instead of globals.Falist.insert(0, globals.images[1])` with maintain codes for two days... Anyone know how can do it? Please help me! * I used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/like_button#:%7E:text=English%20%7C%20%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E7%AE%80%E4%BD%93-,Like%20Button%20is%20a%20flutter%20library%20that%20allows%20you%20to,them%20for%20open%20source%20code) package LikeButton. (and sorry for my poor english...)

Answer (score 0):

```
Expanded(
child: new star()
)
```

```
Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool isLiked) async{
  isLiked ? globals.Falist.removeAt(0) : globals.Falist.insert(0, globals.images[1]) ;
  return !isLiked;
}
```

change ↓

```
Expanded(
child: new LikeButton(
//color setting
),
likeBuilder: (bool isLiked) {
return Icon(
isLiked? Icons.star_rounded : Icons.star_border_rounded,
color: isLiked ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.grey,
size: 34,
);
},
onTap: (bool isLiked) {
return onLikeButtonTapped(isLiked, index);
},
)
)
```

```
Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool isLiked, id) async{
isLiked ? globals.Falist.remove(globals.images[id]) : globals.Falist.insert(0, globals.images[id]);
return !isLiked;
}
```

It works but I don't think this is a best answer...
So if you have any idea, please post it here! Thank you.